# Getting below error while cloning AWS code commit repository while Creating a local copy of the repository

Tags: git, amazon-web-services

Getting below error while cloning AWS code commit repository while Creating a local copy of the repository.

git clone https://git-codecommit.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/field_

fatal: unable to access 'https://git-codecommit.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/field_/': The requested URL returned error: 403

Comment: Have you setup the credentials for using CC?

Answer (score 0):

This is because of your not authorised to clone the repository. please follow the below link to setup your credentials.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-gc.html

```
mainly 4 steps are there

Step 1: Initial configuration for CodeCommit
Step 2: Install Git
Step 3: Set up the credential helper
Step 4: Connect to the CodeCommit console and clone the repository
```